# AWS Lambda "Unable to import moudle"

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I have been trying to create my first Lambda function but every time I run it I get "Unable to import module 'app'".

I have been following the tutorial written by Amazon to create a function that connects to a Amazon RDS db so my Lambda function must include the PyMySQL library.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc-rds-create-rds-mysql.html

I am pretty sure my issue is I am not zipping the contents of the directories correctly therefore the Lambda cannot find my app.py file in order to find the handler and execute.

I have followed the steps to create a deployment package, I have looked at online, create new linux machines, zip in virtual env etc but nothing is working and I get the same error back each time.

Can someone please write down step by step with full commands as what I need to do in order to create the deployment package correctly, or what they do in order to do get their python functions to run in Lambda

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: How does your file structure looks like once deployed to AWS lambda?

Comment: Sorry how do I check this in Lambda?

Comment: @tony25225 if you look at your Lambda function in the AWS console, you'll see an "Actions" button up the top-right, where you can export your function as a zip file.